# I walk up the stairs feeling holy in every step

Tags: expression

does this sentence make sense in this context? Please give me some advices.
the context is:
Every time I step into XXX, I can't stop feeling proud of being a student at XXX. I walk up the stairs feeling holy in every step.  ​​​

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about [english.se] (or [ell.se]) instead of programming.

Comment: I like the tag "expression"! "Expressions" having nothing to do with grammar or emotions!